# Azure Functions: Powershell Push-OutputBinding format JSON

Tags: json, powershell, azure-functions, serverless, azure-powershell

I have used below code in my azure PowerShell HTTP function. On triggering this function, I receive JSON body **but not as in the same order** I have provided in code. Please let me know how can I receive JSON body in response as in same order I have coded i.e. `{"Status": "val", "Msg": "val", "Value": "val"}`

```
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{ 
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Headers = @{
        "Content-type" = "application/json"
    }
    Body = @{
        "Status" = $status
        "Msg" = $body
        "Value" = $val   
    } | ConvertTo-Json
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of keys in a hash table is not determined.

Use an ordered dictionary instead of a hashtable.
This will preserve the order of your keys as you intended them.

To do so, simply add the `[Ordered]` type in front of your `body` hashtable.

```
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{ 
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Headers = @{
        "Content-type" = "application/json"
    }
    # Will keep the order of the keys as specified.
    Body = [Ordered]@{
        "Status" = $status
        "Msg" = $body
        "Value" = $val   
    } | ConvertTo-Json
})
```

> Beginning in PowerShell 3.0, you can use the [ordered] attribute to
> create an ordered dictionary
> (System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary) in PowerShell.
>
> Ordered dictionaries differ from hash tables in that the keys always
> appear in the order in which you list them. The order of keys in a
> hash table is not determined.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2)

Answer (score 0):

N.B. when setting the Content-Type, I found that the method shown above using `Headers=@{...` did not change the content type of the response...

Simply adding `ContentType="..."` *did* seem to work though e.g.:

```
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{ 
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    ContentType = "application/json"
    Body = ...
```